# How to track activity inside iframe of Wordpress tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wp-editor

Im looking for solution that can track user activity inside wp_editor, i mean, i want to know if he is idle or not and then save content as concept (autosaving)

I was trying to use this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fire-event-when-user-is-idle/ and it's working mostly for all elements on website but i can't use it inside wp_editor because it's iframe.

and i tried also this library:
https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle

```
   $('body').idle({
      onIdle: function(){
        $("#workingState").html('<?=displayInLanguage("<p>Stav:   <strong>neaktívny, obsah uložený.</strong></p>", "<p>Status: <strong>inactive, content saved.</strong></p>")?>');

        if( $('#show_add_actuality').hasClass('d-block') ){
            saveForm('actualityForm_sk', "autoSaveScript");
            saveForm('actualityForm_en', "autoSaveScript");
        }
      },
      onActive: function(){
        $("#workingState").html('<?=displayInLanguage("<p>Stav: <strong>aktívny</strong></p>", "<p>Status: <strong>active</strong></p>")?>');
      },
      idle: 2000
    });
```

so as you can see im trying to save form in slovak and english language when user is not active, i will perform ajax request on both forms which includes also wp_editor, but i can't just track activity inside another page (which wp_editor generate another iframe site inside, its blank but still it's not working that way)

So i'm expecting some solution that can help me track user activity inside wordpress editor.

Script is working as expected, the only activity that i can't track is wordpress editor, no typing, no cursor movements nothing it will ignore idle state.

Thanks for any answer.